# How to update recycleview single item while realm database update?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, realm

```
public class MyAdapterMarket extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterMarket.MyViewHolder> {

Context c;
ArrayList<MarketObject> marketObject;
public RecyclerView recyclerView;

public MyAdapterMarket(MarketActivity.MyFragment c, ArrayList<MarketObject> marketObject)  {
    this.marketObject = marketObject;
}

// I AM ABLE TO GET UPDATED OBJECT HERE BUT HOW CAN I UPDATE IN RECYCLEVIEW AT PARTICULAR POSITION. // marketObject.getLast() gives updated value in Realm Database
public static void updateEmployeeListItems(MarketObject marketObject) {
    Log.e("UPDATED OBJECT FROM REALM DATABASE",""+marketObject.getLast());
    }

@Override
public MyAdapterMarket.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.calender_market_list, parent, false);
    return new MyAdapterMarket.MyViewHolder(v);
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView market_title, country_name, market_last, market_time, market_dailyPercentageChange, market_dailyChange;
    public LinearLayout actual, previous, constant;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        c = itemView.getContext();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_fragment_recycleview);
        market_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_title);
        country_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        market_last = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_last);
        market_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_time);
        market_dailyPercentageChange = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_dailyPercentageChange);
        market_dailyChange = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_dailyChange);

    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapterMarket.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final MarketObject market = marketObject.get(position);


    holder.market_title.setText(market.getName());
    holder.country_name.setText(capitalize(market.getCountry()));
    holder.market_last.setText(market.getLast());
    holder.market_time.setText(market.getTime());
    holder.market_dailyPercentageChange.setText(market.getDailypercentualchange());
    holder.market_dailyChange.setText(market.getDailychange());

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Log.v("RECYCLEVIEW POSITION", "Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
            AutoUpdate(position, "0.007");
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MarketDetail.class);
            intent.putExtra( "NAME" , market.getName());
            //context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return marketObject.size();
}
}
```

Give code is my Adapter code, Now I am getting live data of market which update perfectly in Realm Database with MarketObject. I want to reflect that data in Recycleview also with animation so a user can see this market Rate is updated. How does it possible. While updating this value in Realm Database I am passing Object in this function "updateEmployeeListItems()". Now I am not able to update in RecycleView at a particular position.

[In the following Image when I get updates from server I am updating data in Realm Database and as I explain in "updateEmployeeListItems()" I am getting updated object from, Now I want to update this object data in RecycleView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RqcL.png)

Comment: `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` is the right thing, which automatically updates the UI when the data backing the RealmDatabase changes and use `RecyclerView.ItemAnimator` to animate changes.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so if you want to leverage Realm's fine-grained notifications, then you should be using [RealmRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters), and on top of that

```
public class MyAdapterMarket extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<MarketObject, MyAdapterMarket.MyViewHolder> {
    public MyAdapterMarket(OrderedRealmCollection<MarketObject> results  {
        super(results, true, false); // passing `false` to handle `change` manually
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapterMarket.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyAdapterMarket.MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.calender_market_list, parent, false));
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Context c;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;

        TextView market_title, country_name, market_last, market_time, market_dailyPercentageChange, market_dailyChange;
        LinearLayout actual, previous, constant;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            c = itemView.getContext();
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_fragment_recycleview);
            market_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_title);
            country_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
            market_last = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_last);
            market_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_time);
            market_dailyPercentageChange = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_dailyPercentageChange);
            market_dailyChange = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.market_dailyChange);
        }

        RealmObjectChangeListener realmChangeListener = new RealmObjectChangeListener<MarketObject>() {
             @Override
             public void onChange(MarketObject market, ObjectChangeSet changeSet) {
                if(changeSet.isDeleted()) return;

                if(changeSet.isFieldChanged("name")) {
                    market_title.setText(market.getName());
                } 
                if(changeSet.isFieldChanged("country")) {
                    country_name.setText(capitalize(market.getCountry()));
                }
                if(changeSet.isFieldChanged("last")) {
                    market_last.setText(market.getLast());
                }
                if(changeSet.isFieldChanged("time")) {
                    market_time.setText(market.getTime());
                }
                if(changeSet.isFieldChanged("dailypercentualchange")) {
                     market_dailyPercentageChange.setText(market.getDailypercentualchange());
                }
                if(changeSet.isFieldChanged("dailychange")) {
                    market_dailyChange.setText(market.getDailychange());
                }
             }
        }

        MarketObject market;

        public void bind(MarketObject market) {        
            if(this.market != null && this.market.isValid()) {
                this.market.removeAllChangeListeners();
            }
            this.market = market;
            market.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
            market_title.setText(market.getName());
            country_name.setText(capitalize(market.getCountry()));
            market_last.setText(market.getLast());
            market_time.setText(market.getTime());

            market_dailyPercentageChange.setText(market.getDailypercentualchange());
            market_dailyChange.setText(market.getDailychange());

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Log.v("RECYCLEVIEW POSITION", "Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
                    AutoUpdate(position, "0.007");
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MarketDetail.class);
                    intent.putExtra( "NAME" , market.getName());
                    //context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyAdapterMarket.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final MarketObject market = marketObject.get(position);
        holder.bind(market);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only updating one item, you can update your backing list with the new item (i.e. replacing it at old item's index), then tell the `RecyclerView` adapter about the change by calling `recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(POSITION)`, where `POSITION` is the integer index of your updated item in the list/array.

If you get an entire new *list* of items, you can use the `DiffUtil` to find the diff between the old list of backing items and the updated list of backing items, then dispatch those changes to the `RecyclerView` adatper:

---

That being said, user @Saran Sankaran's suggestion of using [`RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/adapter/io/realm/RealmRecyclerViewAdapter.html) is probably what you're looking for. If you use that, you don't need to do any of the `notifyItemChanged` logic yourself.

Comment: Actually, I am using socket.io and getting updated data every second and I am updating it into the realm database. As I mention in cod I am passing Single Object named "marketObject" in "updateEmployeeListItems(MarketObject marketObject)". Now I have no idea about a position, I am confused how I can compare data and update in RecycledView. Can you please provide a snippet of code which I can implement and test in my Adapter?

Comment: I guess I didn't know how to answer, as I was unsure what items you are displaying in your `RecyclerView` (since you don't show how it is getting populated). Are you showing a list of `MarketObjects`, or does the `MarketObject` contain the items you are displaying in the `RecyclerView`? It looks like you're displaying a list of `MarketObject`s. If that's the case, do the `MarketObject`s have any kind of unique identifier you can use to determine which `MarketObject` to replace?

Comment: I think user @Saran Sankaran is right -- you should use a Realm-specific `RecyclerView` adapter for this if you can. My answer only applies if you're using your own adapter.

Comment: I have attached an image of my interface you can see this value "65.41588". Now I am getting the new value every second and I want to update it in RecycleView list(here I am getting new object every second when it updates in database "updateEmployeeListItems(MarketObject marketObject)"). I am new to android so if you can provide little code I can try to implement.

Comment: @hitesh.baldaniya Are you opposed to using the `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`? If you're new to Android, that will make your life much easier.